# xslt Sort over multiple for-each loops on same level

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an xslt stylesheet with multiple for-each loops on the same level. I need the output to be sorted on one element that exists in all loops (IngdatMutVrzm). In the final stylesheet it has five loops, but the idea is the same.

Hope you can help me out here!

Thanks!

```html
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <!-- only the java prefix is declared, the class must be in the current directory -->


<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
<!-- construct the XML document from the source through transformation. -->
<xsl:template mode="applyTagDateNL" match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="node_name" select="substring(concat(local-name(), substring-after(local-name(),'ww_')),(string-length(local-name()) + 1) * number(boolean(substring-after(local-name(),'ww_'))))"/>
    <xsl:variable name="node_text" select="text()"/>
    <xsl:if test="$node_text!= ''">
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring($node_text, 1, 4),    '-',    substring($node_text, 6, 2),    '-',    substring($node_text, 9, 2))"/>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:variable name = "Effective_Date"> 
    <xsl:apply-templates mode="applyTagDateNL" select=".//XX_Absence_Extract/parameters/effective_date"/>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <Verzuimmeldingen xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.sivi.org/Verzuimmanagement/Verzuimmeldingen/2017">
                <xsl:for-each select="HTO_Absence/Absence/Absence_Details">
                <xsl:sort select="IngdatMutVrzm" order="ascending" />
                <xsl:variable name="Absence_Entry_ID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Absence_Entry_ID"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="$Absence_Entry_ID !='' and Absence_Entry_ID_OLD =''">
                <Vrzm>
                    <VrwrkCd>
                        <xsl:text>01</xsl:text>
                    </VrwrkCd>
                    <IngdatMutVrzm>
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="applyTagDateNL" select="IngdatMutVrzm"/>
                    </IngdatMutVrzm>
                    <VrzmgvlId>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Absence_Entry_ID"/>
                    </VrzmgvlId>
                    <VrzmgvlVnrMld>
                        <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
                    </VrzmgvlVnrMld>
                    <EndVrzmJN>
                        <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
                    </EndVrzmJN>
                    <DatVrzmWrkgvr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="applyTagDateNL" select="IngdatMutVrzm"/>
                    </DatVrzmWrkgvr>
                    <DatEerstVrzmdg>
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="applyTagDateNL" select="IngdatMutVrzm"/>
                    </DatEerstVrzmdg>
                    <PrcVrzm>
                        <xsl:text>100</xsl:text>
                    </PrcVrzm>
                    <OorzkVrzmCd>
                        <xsl:if test="OorzkVrzmCd = 'Arbeidsongeval'">
                            <xsl:text>10</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="OorzkVrzmCd = 'Verkeersongeval met regresmogelijkheid'">
                            <xsl:text>11</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="OorzkVrzmCd = 'Overige redenen'">
                            <xsl:text>99</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </OorzkVrzmCd>
                    <VngntCd>
                        <xsl:value-of select="VngntCd"/>
                    </VngntCd>
                    <xsl:if test="Absence_Type !='Verzuimverlof'"> 
                    <WAZOCd>
                        <xsl:if test="Absence_Type = 'Zwangerschaps- en bevallingsverlof'">
                            <xsl:text>01</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="Absence_Type = 'Adoptieverlof'">
                            <xsl:text>02</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </WAZOCd>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="PrcArbther != ''">
                    <PrcArbther>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PrcArbther"/>
                    </PrcArbther>
                    </xsl:if>
                </Vrzm>
                </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                <xsl:for-each select="../../Absence/Absence_Details">
                <xsl:sort select="IngdatMutVrzm" order="ascending" />
                <xsl:variable name="Absence_Entry_ID">
                        <xsl:value-of select="Absence_Entry_ID"/>
                </xsl:variable>
                <xsl:if test="$Absence_Entry_ID !='' and End_Date!='' and Absence_Entry_ID_OLD =''">
                <Vrzm>
                    <VrwrkCd>
                        <xsl:text>02</xsl:text>
                    </VrwrkCd>
                    <xsl:variable name="End_Date">
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="applyTagDateNL" select="End_Date"/>
                    </xsl:variable>
                    <IngdatMutVrzm>
                        <xsl:value-of select="xs:date($End_Date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
                    </IngdatMutVrzm>
                    <VrzmgvlId>
                        <xsl:value-of select="Absence_Entry_ID"/>
                    </VrzmgvlId>
                    <VrzmgvlVnrMld>
                        <xsl:text>3</xsl:text>
                    </VrzmgvlVnrMld>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test = "xs:date($End_Date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') &lt;= $Effective_Date">
                            <EndVrzmJN>
                                <xsl:text>J</xsl:text>
                            </EndVrzmJN>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <EndVrzmJN>
                                <xsl:text>N</xsl:text>
                            </EndVrzmJN>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <DatVrzmWrkgvr>
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="applyTagDateNL" select="IngdatMutVrzm"/>
                    </DatVrzmWrkgvr>
                    <DatEerstVrzmdg>
                        <xsl:apply-templates mode="applyTagDateNL" select="IngdatMutVrzm"/>
                    </DatEerstVrzmdg>
                    <xsl:if test="$End_Date != ''">
                    <DatHrstld>
                        <xsl:value-of select="xs:date($End_Date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D')"/>
                    </DatHrstld>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test = "xs:date($End_Date) + xs:dayTimeDuration('P1D') &lt;= $Effective_Date">
                            <PrcVrzm>
                                <xsl:text>0</xsl:text>
                            </PrcVrzm>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <PrcVrzm>
                                <xsl:value-of select="PrcVrzm"/>
                            </PrcVrzm>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                    <OorzkVrzmCd>
                        <xsl:if test="OorzkVrzmCd = 'Arbeidsongeval'">
                            <xsl:text>10</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="OorzkVrzmCd = 'Verkeersongeval met regresmogelijkheid'">
                            <xsl:text>11</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="OorzkVrzmCd = 'Overige redenen'">
                            <xsl:text>99</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </OorzkVrzmCd>
                    <VngntCd>
                        <xsl:value-of select="VngntCd"/>
                    </VngntCd>
                    <xsl:if test="Absence_Type !='Verzuimverlof'"> 
                    <WAZOCd>
                        <xsl:if test="Absence_Type = 'Zwangerschaps- en bevallingsverlof'">
                            <xsl:text>01</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:if test="Absence_Type = 'Adoptieverlof'">
                            <xsl:text>02</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:if>
                    </WAZOCd>
                    </xsl:if>
                    <xsl:if test="PrcArbther != ''">
                    <PrcArbther>
                        <xsl:value-of select="PrcArbther"/>
                    </PrcArbther>
                    </xsl:if>
                </Vrzm>
                </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
                
</xsl:template>
</xsl:transform>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without seeing the whole context I'd go with this idea:

Have only one for-each that would go over all the Absence_Details and sort them:

```
<xsl:for-each select="HTO_Absence/Absence/Absence_Details | ../../Absence/Absence_Details">
  <xsl:sort select="IngdatMutVrzm" order="ascending" />
  ...
</xsl:for-each>
```

Then in that for-each use a xsl:choose to dertermine which "type" of element your are on and call an appropriate template using the mode attribute.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Hi Sebastien, Thanks a lot for your quick reply! The reason that I used several for each loops is that, depending on the values, an input record has an output in more then one of the loops. To give you more context, my input is an absence record from an hcm system. That has a start and end date. This has to be split in a 'new absence' record and a 'recovery' record. In one loop the IngdatMutVrzm is the start date of the input record, in the next loop it is the end date of the record. Does this make sense?

Comment: Couldn't you only have one for-each and then for every input element you create two output elements (call 2 templates in each iteration).

Comment: That's it, I just made it too complicated and didn't see it. Many Thanks Sebastien!